# How to loop over files and save output in different files using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command

I have two different files A.txt and B.txt both containing the same string.
I would like to use a `sed` command in order to replace the strings but I do not want to overwrite A.txt and B.txt.

Actually I would like to loop over files and then do something like this for both :

```
sed 's/myString/myNewString/g' A.txt > updatedA.txt
```

What trick can I use in order to redirect outputs this way for as many files as I want ? Let's assume I've got x *.txt files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `for` loop for all .txt files in current directory:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  sed 's/myString/myNewString/g' "$file" > "updated$file"
done
```

Use this script only once per directory.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel sed 's/myString/myNewString/g' {} \> updated{} ::: *.txt
```

This will loop through all txt files in the current directory and make amendments/copies to new files prefixed by `updated`.

If you only want create files for those with changes, use:

```
parallel grep myString {} \&\& sed 's/myString/myNewString/g' {} \> updated{} ::: *.txt
```

Or re-curse through all `txt` files in a directory, use:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | parallel sed 's/myString/myNewString/g' {} \> {//}/updated{/}
```