# Find Remove all characters after :202::TEST// and :200::DATE1//

Tags: python, pandas

**
This is a  old.txt file:

### :100:ABCD
:120:HELP
:202:TEST//1234567
:203:PROD//
:230:NEWBEE
:240:DDDD//
:250:FFFF//
:200::DATE1//01-01-2019
:300::DATE2//
:100:ABCD

The new file.txt file should look like

### :100:ABCD
:120:HELP
:202:TEST//
:203:PROD//
:230:NEWBEE
:240:DDDD//
:250:FFFF//
:200::DATE1//
:300::DATE2//
:100:ABCD

***This is what I have now but this will not remove

```
import os
texttofind= ':202::TEST//'
texttoreplace= ':202::TEST//{{TEST}}'
sourcepath = os.listdir('/Users/Testin/')
for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile = '/Users/Testin/' + file
    print ('Convert is now ongoing :' +inputfile)
    with open (inputfile, 'r') as inputfile:
        filedata = inputfile.read()
        freq= 0
        freq = filedata.count(texttofind)
    destiationpath= '/Users/Testout/' + file
    filedata = filedata.replace(texttofind,texttoreplace)
    with open(destiationpath,'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
    print ('Total %d Records Replaced' %freq)
```

**
The result is this...(but I need the number 1234567(or any other number or character, to be removed before it can be replaced)

```
:10A:ABCD
:120:HELP
:202::TEST//{{TEST}}1234567
:203::PROD//
:230:NEWBEE
:240::DDDD//EEEE
:250::FFFF//FFFF
:20::DATE1//01012019
:30::DATE2//
:10B:ABCD
 -}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: how is this related to pandas?

Comment: I have tried to split the file df[['AB','CD']] = df.line.str.split("TEST//",expand=True)
print(df) But this did not work

Comment: this is what I have:

Comment: import os
texttofind= ':202::TEST//'
texttoreplace= ':202::TEST//{{TEST}}'

Comment: I need to updated several txt files but there are more if and then statements that should be carried out so 'sed' is not an option. I need a program more then just search and replace..@mozway

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I have tried to solve it with panda because at the end I want to export the result to excel. So therefore I mentioned pandas.

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't need pandas, and even not python for that.

You could use [`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's|//[^ /]*|//|g' old.txt >new.txt
```

Comment: thanks but I can't use sed. I need all files from the directory testin to be adjusted and stored in directory testout. Upfront I dont know the name.

Comment: @HaCu this doesn't prevent you from using `sed`, what you need is to loop over the files and save them in the other folder during processing. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611833/how-to-loop-over-files-and-save-output-in-different-files-using-sed)